# Nested sql how to do?

Tags: mysql, sql

My input is only userid. How do i combine three tables to get area name. I am pretty sure my syntax is correct

> TABLE NAME: userinfo userid PRIMARY KEY
>
> TABLE NAME: userinfo_attarea employee_id FOREIGN KEY userid REFERENCE
>   userinfo area_id FOREIGN KEY area_id REFERENCE personnel area
>
> TABLE NAME: personnel area area_id PRIMARY KEY areaname

I tried with this but failed,

```
SELECT areaname FROM userinfo a
INNER JOIN (SELECT *FROM userinfo_attarea b
INNER JOIN SELECT *FROM personnel_area c
ON b.areaid = c.areaid
) b ON a.userid = b.employee_id;
```

Comment: You have too may alias b in the query.

Comment: the the two alias 'b' are not related. The first alias is for table ==> userinfo_attarea and second alias for result of table ==> select * from userinfo_attarea b join select * from personnel_area c on b.areaid = c.areaid

Comment: I dont find any error in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you this query will help you

```
select areaname from personel_area pa inner join
userinfo_attarea ut on pa.area_id=ut.area_id
inner join userinfo ui on ut.employee_id=ui.userid
```

Comment: Is there any syntax error in my query above? I think it should work too. I cant seem to find the issue. But yours is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

select b.areaname
  from userinfo a INNER JOIN ( SELECT c.areaname FROM  ( select *
                                                  from userinfo_attarea ) b
                                                   INNER JOIN ( select *
                                                                  from personnel_area ) c on b.areaid = c.areaid
                                ) b on a.userid = b.employee_id;

Answer (score 0):

Your correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT areaname FROM userinfo a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM userinfo_attarea b
    INNER JOIN personnel_area c
    ON b.areaid = c.areaid
) b ON a.userid = b.employee_id;
```

The `SLELECT * FROM` on third line is unnecessary.

Also, I strongly recommend proper indentation and correct use of spaces :) (`* FROM` instead of `*FROM`). It will increase clarity of your code.

Also, you need to take care of column names, as sometimes they can be ambigious, so you should list them explicitly in inner query and give them unique aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is NOT correct.  You are using parentheses unnecessarily in the `FROM` clause.  You are NOT using parentheses for subqueries.

The subqueries are entirely unnecessary.  In addition, you have a poor choice of table aliases (random letters rather than table abbreviations) and you haven't qualified your table names.

```
SELECT pa.areaname
FROM userinfo ui INNER JOIN
     userinfo_attarea uia
     ON uia.employee_id = ui.userid INNER JOIN
     personnel_area pa
     ON uia.areaid = pa.areaid;
```